# C++ passing "this" instance to property in class

Tags: c++, pointers

I have this code

```
void Field::tick() {
    this->snake.tick(this);
}
```

where `this->snake` is a class property of the `Snake` class.
The `Snake` class takes `this` parameters in the `tick()` method:

```
void tick(Field field);
```

Of course, in the header file of `Snake`, I imported `Field.h`.

Now the problem is upon passing an instance of `this` in the field class to the `tick()` method in `Snake`, I get the following error:

```
c:/Users/x/Documents/NetBeansProjects/snake/Snake.h:12:15: fout: Field has not been declared
c:/Users/x/Documents/NetBeansProjects/snake/Field.cpp: In memberfunction void Field::tick():
c:/Users/x/Documents/NetBeansProjects/snake/Field.cpp:14:27: fout: no matching function for call to Snake::tick(Field&)
c:/Users/x/Documents/NetBeansProjects/snake/Field.cpp:14:27: note: candidate is:
c:/Users/x/Documents/NetBeansProjects/snake/Snake.h:12:10: note: void Snake::tick(int)
c:/Users/x/Documents/NetBeansProjects/snake/Snake.h:12:10: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from Field to int
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: That first error indicates that you do not, in fact, include the `Field.h` header file (or not correctly)

Answer (score 1):

In file *Snake.h*, declare class `Field` before the declaration of class `Snake`:

```
class Field;

class Snake
{
    ...
    void tick(Field* field);
    ...
};
```

This should fix the compilation error, because you are using **a pointer** of class `Field` in class `Snake`. So the compiler only needs to know that such class exists, but it doesn't need to know anything about the contents of that class. If you were using an instance, then you would get a compilation error, because the compiler would need to know the size of that instance.

Therefore, the alternative option of declaring class `Snake` before the declaration of class `Field` will not compile, because you are using **an instance** of class `Field` in class `Snake`, and the compiler needs to know the size of that instance:

```
class Snake;

class Field
{
    ...
    Snake snake;
    ...
};
```

Comment: He said that he imports the `Field` header file in the `Snake` one

Comment: I think there is a circular dependency between Field and Snake, so he needs to do forward declaration as Barak Manos suggested

Comment: @CoffeeandCode: But class `Field` has a member of type `Snake`, hence, both classes need to know of each other. Hence, at least one of them should use an "empty" declaration such as `class Field;` (it cannot be `class Snake;` in file Field.h, because that one uses an actual instance of type `Snake`).

Comment: @elaurens yes, but the circular dependency is the other way around than this answer suggests (if `Field` **is** properly defined in `Field.h`)

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it. One question though, is it considered good practice to have circular dependencies? Or does it just lead to more problems?

Comment: @Raoul Van den Berge: You're welcome. Please see updated answer for a brief explanation.

Comment: I'm having still a problem with the Snake property though, the property "Snake snake;" in Field is giving the error that it "does not name a type", even though I included Snake.h.

Comment: @Raoul Van den Berge: I suggest that you add the relevant parts of your code (at least the declaration of **both** classes) to the question.

Comment: Sure, no problem. See this: https://gist.github.com/rvandenberge/ac9471337f349d3acc24

Comment: @Raoul Van den Berge: You need to use `#ifndef\#define\#endif` in each one of your header files!!!

Comment: Doesn't #pragma once do the same thing?

Comment: @Raoul Van den Berge: Well it does, but it's not a part of the standard, so I'm not sure whether or not it's supported on your platform (preprocessor/compiler).

Comment: @Raoul Van den Berge: Also, why do you `#include "Snake.h"` inside file *Snake.h* itself???

Comment: My mistake! Seems to be fixed now, thanks for the explanation.